# Flag manifold to Complex Projective line

Tags: geometry

I am trying to get some intuition about the simplest flag manifold  $ U(2)/T^2 $  which is apparently given by $ CP^1\cong S^2 $ . I have understood the stereographic projection of $ S^2 $ onto the complex plane. But I don't understand how $ U(2)/T^2 \cong CP^1 $. Can anyone tell me how this projection works?

Comment: Counter question for calibration: Do you understand the set of complex lines through the origin in $\mathbf{C}^2$, and do you understand the stereographic projection picture in this setting?

Comment: No. I can imagine it has to do with using the usual argument of using unit vectors in $ C^2 $ as rays and each of these rays correspond to a unique point on $ CP^1 $ . How do rigorously write down the transformation.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a picture:
[image: Lines through the origin in the plane]

First, view the picture "literally", as $\mathbf{R}^2$ equipped with Cartesian coordinates $(z_0, z_1)$. Every real line through the origin crosses at least one of the lines $V_1 = \{z_0=1\}$ or $V_0 = \{z_1=1\}$. (The $z_0$-axis misses $V_0$, the $z_1$-axis misses $V_1$.) Each "affine coordinate neighborhood" $V_i$ is a "copy" of $\mathbf{R}$, and the respective affine coordinates are related by $z_0z_1 = 1$.

The circle of unit vectors in $\mathbf{R}^2$ is denoted $S$. Each real line through the origin cuts $S$ in a unit $0$-sphere, i.e., in a pair of antipodal points (labeled $U$).

Further, each real line hits the circle labeled $\mathbf{P}^1$ exactly twice: once at the origin, and once at an arbitrary point of the circle. (The $z_1$-axis is tangent to the small circle, i.e., "hits the circle twice at the origin".) Consequently, *the real projective line may be viewed as the small circle*. Projection away from the origin is stereographic projection from $\mathbf{P}^1$ to the affine coordinate neighborhood $V_1$.

Now view the picture "figuratively", as $\mathbf{C}^2$, and think of *complex* lines through the origin. The affine coordinate neighborhoods are defined exactly as before. Each is a "copy" of $\mathbf{C}$ in $\mathbf{C}^2$, and except for the axes, every complex line through the origin hits each affine coordinate neighborhood exactly once.

The set $S$ of unit vectors is the $3$-sphere $S^3$, and each complex line through the origin intersects $S$ in a unit circle $U$. (These circles are the "fibres of the Hopf map".)

In this interpretation, $\mathbf{P}^1$ is not sitting in $\mathbf{C}^2$ in a nice way; however, it may still be viewed abstractly as the result of attaching the two complex lines $V_0$ and $V_1$ by identifying $z_1$ and $1/z_0$, so *the complex projective line is a real $2$-sphere*.

So, finally, the original question boils down to: The group $U(2)$ of unitary $2 \times 2$ matrices acts transitively on the space of complex lines through the origin in $\mathbf{C}^2$, and the stabilizer of a line is isomorphic to a real $2$-torus. (Each coordinate axis is invariant by the diagonal subgroup, for example.)

Comment: Firstly, I would like to thank you for the time and effort you have taken to answer my question.
Secondly, I was wondering why you have considered 2 subspaces $ V_0 , V_1 $. Can we rather just consider one of them and assume that line along $ z_1 $ axis meets $ V_1 $ at infinity($ \pm $)?

Comment: You're very welcome. :) The introduction of two lines makes your intuition about infinity precise, by ensuring that _every_ line properly hits one of the coordinate neighborhoods. (If you consider the projective _plane_, the set of lines through the origin in a three-dimensional space, the need for multiple coordinate systems becomes more apparent; it's potentially tricky to see what happens at infinity otherwise.)