# Are Möbius transformations holomorphic or meromorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

In my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1178966/is-there-a-geometric-insight-from-this-exercise) it was pointed out to me that an "automorphism" of the projective line/Riemann sphere (=that is a Möbius transform) is a bijection that is **meromorphic** in the local coordinate z.

Since I didn't know Möbius transforms I tried to find information about them and then [on Wikipedia about Möbus transofmrs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) it is stated that Möbius transformations are exactly the bijective **conformal maps** from the Riemann sphere to itself.

[But it is also stated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Definition) that it is a bijective **holomorphic** function from the Riemann sphere to the Riemann sphere.

I understand that meromorphic is weaker than holomorphic but it's not clear to me where conformal fits in. But mostly it's not clear to me which of these is right.

While I was trying to find out which of these 3 descriptions is correct I [found out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Decomposition_and_elementary_properties) that every Möbius transofrm can be composed into translations, scaling and $z \mapsto 1/z$. Then maybe using this composition, if $1/z$ is holomorphic then so is the Möbius transform?

> Is a Möbius transform holomorphic (or just meromorphic or conformal) on the Riemann sphere?

and

> Is $1/z$ holomorphic on the Riemann sphere?

Comment: Note that the function $f(z)=1/z$ is not a holomorphic function, for it has a pole of order $1$ at $z=0$ since $f(z)=1/z$ is its own Laurent Expansion in a neighborhood of $0$. I assume what they mean is that any Mobius transformation is locally holomorphic.

It is good to note that every holomorphic function on a compact, connected complex manifold is constant as can be seen [here](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Maximum-modulus_principle).

Comment: @Eoin viewed as a map from the Riemann sphere into itself, $f$ is holomorphic, isn't it? I think the question "Is $1/z$ holomorphic on the Riemann sphere?" is a little ambiguous, because it's not clear which target space Anna is considering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generic Möbius transformation is a *meromorphic function* on $\mathbb{C}$, and a *holomorphic map* of the Riemann sphere onto itself. There  is a difference between "function" and "map" here.

- Holomorphic function: a function with values in $\mathbb{C}$ which is locally represented by its Taylor series
- Meromorphic function: a function with values in $\mathbb{C}$ which is locally represented by its Laurent series with finitely many negative powers
- Holomorphic map: a map between complex manifolds such that appropriate compositions with chart maps are holomorphic.

When the Riemann sphere is equipped with the structure of a complex manifold, a neighborhood of $\infty$ is covered by the coordinate patch $z\mapsto 1/z$. A function with a pole qualifies as a holomorphic map into the sphere, because at a point $a$ where $f(a)=\infty$, the composition with the above chart map is $1/f$ (which is holomorphic).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand it better now.