# show that the phase curves are great circles

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

this question from In V.I.Arnold's book about ordinary differential equations. I'm having difficulty with problem after the example of small oscillations of a spherical pendulum can please help me for the problem.the problem is prove that the phase curves are great circles of these spheres however, not every great circle of a sphere is a phase curves.

We have the system of differential equations
$$
x'_1=x_2 \quad x'_2=−x_1\\
x'_3=x_4 \quad x'_4=−x_3.
$$

please help me to solve this problem. thanks

Comment: What do $x_{1,2,3,4}$ represent?

Comment: Please check how far https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185117/phase-curve-of-ddotx-x-ddoty-y?rq=1 answers your questions.