# Finding the images under a Mobius transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation, inversive-geometry

Let $L1$ be the $x$-axis, let $L2$ be the $y$-axis and let $L3$ be the vertical line $x = 1$.
For each $k ∈ Z$ let $C_{k}$ denote the circle of radius $r = 1/2$ with centre $z = 1/2 + ki$. 
Let $f(z) = {2z}/{(z+1)}$.

**1)** Sketch $L1, L2, L3$ and the circles $C_{k}$.

**2)** Show that $f(z)$ maps $L1$ to itself and find the images $f(L2)$, $f(L3)$ and $f(C_{0})$ under the transformation $f(z)$.

I have attempted to sketch the points, I believe I should end up with circles one above each other but not sure?

I'm struggling with part 2) too. I'm told as a hint to consider the angles between $L1, L2, L3$ and $C_{0}$ but don't know how to use this. In my attempt I have just subbed say $z=iy$ for $L2$ to represent the y axis. I then did the same for 3 points on the circle  to end up with $f(1/2)=2/3, f(-1/2) = -2$ and $f(i/2) = 2i/5+1/5$ but I have no idea whether this is right or where I would go from here as finally I am asked to produce another sketch of all of the **images** of the points without any further calculations.

Answer (score 1):

For the circle $C_0$ I think that the approach you have taken is correct, by looking at $3$ points on the circle and studying where they get mapped.
But note that the points you chose are *not* on $C_0$.

$C_0$ is the circle around $z=1/2$ with radius $r=1/2$.
Let's look at $$z_1 = 1,\ \ z_2=\frac{1}{2} + \frac{i}{2}, \ \ z_3 = 0$$
under $f(z) = \frac{2z}{z+1}$ we have:
$$ f(z_1) = 1, \ \ f(z_2) = \frac{4}{5}-\frac{2}{5}i, \ \ f(z_3) = 0$$

Since we know that Mobius transformations map circles and lines to circles or lines, we can check that these $3$ points lie on the same $C_0$ circle around $z=1/2$ with radius $r=1/2$.

I hope this helps.

**Update**:
To show that $f(z_1),\ f(z_2),\ f(z_3)$ lie on $C_0$ we can follow the steps in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/213670/201454

We get the following $3$ equations:
$$(1-x_c)^2 + y_c^2 -r^2 = 0$$
$$(\frac{4}{5}-x_c)^2 + (-\frac{2}{5} - y_c)^2 -r^2 = 0$$
$$x_c^2 + y_c^2 -r^2 = 0$$

Subtracting the third equation from the first gives:
$$1 - 2x_c = 0 \implies x_c=\frac{1}{2}$$

Subtracting the third equation from the second gives:
$$\frac{16}{25}-\frac{8}{5}x_c + \frac{4}{25} + \frac{4}{5}y_c = 0
\implies \frac{4}{5} - \frac{8}{5}x_c + \frac{4}{5}y_c = 0$$

Plugging in $x_c=1/2$ gives $y_c=0$

Now plug in $x_c=1/2,\ y_c=0$ in the third equation to get $r=1/2$

Comment: Thank you! How would I show exactly that those 3 new points still lie on $C_0$?

Comment: You can follow the steps in http://math.stackexchange.com/a/213670/201454

Comment: Okay, using what for the coordinates exactly as they are complex? Would I use say $x=4/5$ and $y= 2/5$ For $f(z2)$?

Comment: That should be a -2/5 for y sorry

Comment: As I followed the steps with the coordinates this way and have ended up with a centre of $(1/2 +i/2, i/4)$ but this would not be the same circle so not quite sure where I've gone wrong.

Comment: Yes, you need to use $x=4/5,\ y=-2/5$.
I will update my answer later. If you want you can double check your calculations. You can also verify that the distance between $f(z_2)$ and $1/2$ is $1/2$.

Comment: I've got it now thank you! So would L3 the line x=1 be mapped to the point 2?. I'm understanding bits and pieces of this question now but am still struggling to put it all together. And why is it I have been given the hint to consider the angles between my lines and circle? As we haven't needed to use it so far.

Comment: No, $L_3$ is a line, so under a Mobius transformation it must be mapped to a line or a circle. Try to apply the same method I used in my answer, and look at $3$ points, e.g. $1,\ 1+i,\ \infty$ and their mapping under $f$ and try to determine what is $f(L_3).$
I am honestly not sure why the hint is helpful here. I think that the method I showed is simple enough to apply.

Comment: okay thank you so much for your help! Okay I will do that but I don't quite understand how $1+i$ lies on the line x=1? And when I do the map for $L1$ what would the three points be there? Is it infinity, 0 and something?

Comment: The points on the line $x=1$ are represented as $z=1+ti$ where $t$ is real.
When you map $L_1$ you can choose e.g. $0,\ 1,\ \infty$

Comment: So for L2 the y axis, do I chose the points $0, i$ and infinity? After performing the map I end up with 0, infinity and $-1-i$ so does it just map to another line? I think this is wrong because the previous answer to this question suggests it maps to a circle.

Comment: $0,\ i,\ \infty$ are good choices for $L_2$. These points are mapped to $0,\ i+1,\ 2$ respectively. So $f(L_2)$ is the circle around $z=1$ with radius $r=1$.

Comment: if infinity gets mapped to 2 how is the line L1 mapped to itself? As it would get mapped to 0,1 and 2. $\not=$ L1 as there is no point of infinity to produce the line?

Answer (score 0):

(partial answer)

Let us consider the image of $(L_2)$ by function $f$.

The idea is to describe the "generic element" $z \in (L_2)$ as being:

$$z=i t , \ \ \ t \in \mathbb{C}, \ \ \text{giving} \ \ \ f(it)=\frac{2it}{it+1}$$

Let us now convert this expression in order that the denominator doesn't contain any more a complex non-real number. This is done by multiplying the numerator and the denominator of this fraction by the conjugate expression of the denominator, i.e.,

$$f(it)=\frac{2it(-it+1)}{(it+1)(-it+1)}=\frac{2t^2+i2t}{1+t^2}=x+iy \ \ \text{with} \ \ \cases{x=\frac{2t^2}{1+t^2}\\y=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}}$$

or in a more interesting manner, by a $-1$ translation on the $x$ axis:

$$\cases{x-1=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\\y=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}}$$

These are the well known parametric equations for the unit circle (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1246832)). All the unit circle is reached but one point. Could you find it?

Thus the looked for image of $(L_2)$ is circle is with center $(1,0)$ and radius $1$.

Indeed one checks that $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$;

But in fact there is a missing point which is $(0,2)$ which is never "reached".

Edit: Circle $(C_0)$ is parametrically described as being the set of complex numbers of the form: $$z=\frac12+\frac12 e^{it}=\frac12+\frac12(\cos(t)+i \sin(t)).$$

Thus, the image of circle $(C_0)$ by transformation $f$ is thus the set of points of the form:

$$f(z)=\dfrac{(1+\cos(t))+i \sin(t)}{(\frac32+\frac12 \cos(t))+i (\frac12 \sin(t))}$$

You just have to multiply, as before, the numerator and the denominator by the conjugate of the denominator.

Comment: thank you that's helped me see things a bit clearer but I'm still a bit stuck when it comes to the circle $C_0$. Are the points I've chosen to transform correct? If so I'm struggling to see where they go to. None of the points are sent to infinity under the mapping so I know it is not a line so does this mean the image is another circle?

Comment: Yes, on this ground, it should be another circle. Besides I have added an Edit to my answer.