# How does $\mathbb{P^1}$ identify with $S^1$?

Tags: equivalence-relations, projective-geometry

Let $\mathbb{P^1}$ be the set of all lines $\mathbb{R^2}$  passing through the origin.
And by the definition of the unit circle $S^1 =  \left[0,1\right]/\sim$ , $\left[0,1\right]$ are identified.

What does it mean that  $\mathbb{P^1}$ identifies with $S^1$?

What I supposed is that by definition $ S^1 \subset \mathbb{P^1}$.

Am I missing the point? What does it mean by "identifies with"?

Comment: Hint: If two points are "identified" they are to be treated as though they were the exact same point.  A way of looking at this is that you take the two points and glue one on top of the other (take the unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and identify the left and right hand sides.  You should be able to see (use a sheet of paper if it helps) that this produces a cylinder).

Comment: $\mathbb{RP}^1$ identifies with $\mathbb{S}^1$ means that they are homeomorphic

Comment: @postmortes I can see how two opposites sides of a unit square can form a cylinder when the opposite sides are glued together, but the notation is somewhat new and a bit confusing to me. How does $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ creat a unit square exactly? I have to consider $[0,1]\times[0,1]$  as two lines, the first line creates a circle, and the other one "slides through" that circle creating a cylinder correct? How is this sliding effect called, spanning? Sorry, I am a complete beginner as you can see. Or is it two parallel lines gluing together?

Comment: $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ is the set $\{(x,y) \mid x\in[0,1] \mbox{ and } y\in[0,1] \}$, so it's every point in that square.  When we identify points they're the same, so if you go left from $(0,0)$ you move to $(\epsilon,0)$ for $\epsilon >0$ and if you go right you move to $(1-\epsilon ,0)$

Comment: [Possibly of interest](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447567/flag-manifold-to-complex-projective-line)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $C=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1, x\geq 0, \}$, it is the half-circle it is an interval. every line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is different of $\{y=0\}$ meets this half-circle in exactly one point. The line $\{y,0\}$ meets $C$ in $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$. This defines a bijection between the projective plane and the quotient of $C$ with $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ identified which is the circle.

Answer (score 1):

You already know by definition, $\Bbb RP^1$ is homeomorphic to $S^1/x\sim -x$ where $x\in S^1$.

Hint: 1. We have a commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} D^1 @>i>> S^1\\ @Vf VV @VVgV\\ D^1/\sim @>k>> S^1/\sim \end{CD}$$

where $i$ is a natural inclusion map and $k$ is an induced map that makes the diagram commutes and $f,g$ are quotient maps. Here, $D^1/\sim$ is just an identification of two endpoints. Using the definition of quotient topology, show that $k$ is a continuous map.

2. Recall the theorem: a continuous bijective map $f:X\to Y$ where $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff is a homeomorphism.
3. Conclude $D^1/\sim\ \cong\ S^1/\sim$.

Remark. Using the same argument, we can show that $D^n/\sim\ \cong\ S^n/\sim$

Answer (score 0):

Take the line y=1  in $\mathbb{R^2}$. Then, clearly you can define a bijection between this line and the set of lines through the origin without x=0 (every such line cuts y=1). So, the whole set of lines through the origin is in bijection with $\mathbb{R}$ plus a point, which itself is one-to-one with the circle.
Now you can also show that this is not only a bijection but also an homeomorphism if you define a certain natural topology on the set of lines through the origin.

Comment: what is meant by " $\mathbb{R}$ plus a point"? Shouldn't it be minus a point? I am taking a first-year geometry course, so I am not yet acquainted with topology, unfortunately.

Comment: You have to make a drawing while reading my previous answer, you will understand much better. $\mathbb{R}$ plus a point because y=1 is in bijection with $\mathbb{R}$, but you have to add another point corresponding to x=0 to get the bijection with the set of lines through the origin.